# Select count of users over two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I want to count the occurrence of the same user id in two tables. 
The `jos_findme` table has all the users in it. The other two have as well the column "user id".

But I want the overall count in the two tables. I tried this but it does not work?

```
SELECT 
    c.user_id, count(c.user_id) AS counter
FROM
    jos_findme as c
        LEFT JOIN
    jos_findme_bestof as b ON b.user_id = c.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    jos_findme_pair as p ON p.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE
    c.user_id > 0
GROUP BY c.user_id
ORDER BY counter DESC
LIMIT 10
```

ALL tables have the column "user_id". I just want to count them in the tables "jos_findme_bestof" and "jos_findme_pair"

Comment: over all count as in? user_id's common  in both tables or user_id either in one of the tables? please elaborate on the criteria and the table definitions

Comment: can you add database schema or sample data, what you actually need? it would be better for us to guess things.

Comment: ALL tables have the column "user_id". I just want to count them in the tables "jos_findme_bestof" and "jos_findme_pair"

Answer (score 2):

Correlated subqueries could be useful here:

```
SELECT c.user_id, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   jos_findme_bestof b 
        WHERE  b.user_id = c.user_id), 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   jos_findme_pair p 
        WHERE  p.user_id = c.user_id) 
FROM   jos_findme c
```

Comment: I am using SELECT c.user_id, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_bestof b WHERE b.user_id = c.user_id) as bCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_pair   p WHERE p.user_id = c.user_id) as pCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_style  s WHERE s.user_id = c.user_id) as sCount
       
FROM   jos_findme c But I cannot add a "total" column?

Comment: @user2881954: It wasn't clear from your question that you needed such a column.  One could simply replace the comma separating the subqueries in my answer above with an addition `+` operator; however, [@Mzf's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21377598) is likely to be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT AA.user_id, AA.Acounter + BB.Bcounter
from     (SELECT a.user_id, count(a.user_id) AS Acounter
          FROM jos_findme_bestof as a
          GROUP BY a.user_id) as AA 
     Join  
        (SELECT b.user_id, count(b.user_id) AS Bcounter
          FROM jos_findme_pair as b
          GROUP BY b.user_id) as BB
     on AA.user_id = BB.user_id
```

if you wants all the ids (meaning if there are id's in jos_findme_pair that are not in jos_findme_bestof) - use `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: sorry but what is t.user_id?

Comment: PERFECT it works !!!!! Small question how would it lock like with 3 tables adding "jos_findme_style"

Comment: adding 1 more join for "jos_findme_style" , the same way I added "jos_findme_pair" as CC and add it to the top select. I think this should work

Comment: SELECT AA.user_id, AA.Acounter + BB.Bcounter + CC.Ccounter
from     (SELECT a.user_id, count(a.user_id) AS Acounter
          FROM jos_findme_bestof as a
          GROUP BY a.user_id) as AA 
     Join  
        (SELECT b.user_id, count(b.user_id) AS Bcounter
          FROM jos_findme_pair as b
          GROUP BY b.user_id) as BB
      on AA.user_id = BB.user_id
      
       Join  
        (SELECT c.user_id, count(c.user_id) AS Ccounter
          FROM jos_findme_style as c
          GROUP BY c.user_id) as CC
        on AA.user_id = CC.user_id

Comment: Sorry but one more question. How can I now add a WHERE to the user table "jos:findme"? Like WHERE username = "max" AND there is an error: it shows only user ids which are in ALL 3 tables ;-)

Comment: Chris Moffatt [licensed that image](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/) under [CPOL](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx), term 3(e) of which states "*The Articles discussing the Work published in any form by the author may not be distributed or republished without the Author's consent. The author retains copyright to any such Articles. You may use the Executable Files and Source Code pursuant to this License but you may not repost or republish or otherwise distribute or make available the Articles, without the prior written consent of the Author.*"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT c.user_id,
       Users1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_bestof b WHERE b.user_id = c.user_id),
       Users2 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_pair p WHERE p.user_id = c.user_id),
       TotalUser = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_bestof b WHERE b.user_id = c.user_id)
       +
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_pair p WHERE p.user_id= c.user_id)
FROM   
jos_findme c
```

Here, 
Users1 will return all users from `jos_findme_bestof`
Users2 will return all users from `jos_findme_pair`
TotalUser will be count of both the tables

Hope it would helps you!
Thanks.

Comment: Unknown column 'c.UserID' in 'field list' How can I fix this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. That was bcz i have created `UserID` instead of `user_id` in my test database. Now all set, test it and let me know if you still have any problems!

Comment: sorry but i get: Unknown column 'Users1' in 'field list'

Comment: Are you using `mysql` or `sql`? I have prepared and tested query for `sql`. And also paste you query here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.user_id, (IFNULL(b.bCount, 0) + IFNULL(p.pCount, 0)) AS counter
FROM jos_findme AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.user_id, COUNT(1) bCount 
           FROM jos_findme_bestof b 
           GROUP BY b.user_id 
         ) AS b ON b.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.user_id, COUNT(1) pCount 
           FROM jos_findme_pair p 
           GROUP BY p.user_id 
         ) AS p ON p.user_id = c.user_id 
WHERE c.user_id > 0
GROUP BY c.user_id
ORDER BY counter DESC
LIMIT 10
```